# Minimum Plywood Thickness for small "crate"

Tags: plywood

I've never done any woodwork in my life but I wanted to try.

I thought about making a simple shelf consisting of a few small crate-like boxes (Each box being 60cm in Length, 15cm in Width and 20cm in Height and the shelf itself would be about 120cm tall, or 6-crates tall) and was think about having a 2cmX2cm long vertical square "pole" at the corners and a 1cmx2cm rail instead of a full side for each crate that would meet at the corners in a channel carved in the poles and touch in a 45º edge to the other rail of a corner. Something like this:

[image]

(Left to Right: 2cmX2cm pole with the 2cmX1cm channel cut through, the side rails in place, topside view of the join area ignoring the rest of the pole that would be on top of the joint)

My Idea for each crate would be something like this:
[image]

(Top-down and Side views of each crate, respectively)

I'd like to know if I use solid wood for the poles and plywood for the rails and bottom of each crate, in the dimensions mentioned, would it be strong enough? Do I need thicker plywood/wood for the structure to be able to hold?

I imagine this can be hard to predict, but I hoped someone experienced would have a better view on that and maybe point some obvious mistake I can't see.

Thank you very much for the attention!

Comment: This might be a bit too broad for SE sites, as you are asking a lot of related questions, and any answer is likely to be incomplete. That is, with what you have given here, the answer to the question in the title is "probably, yes". But then there are a whole bunch of related questions that might change that... It'll be hard to give you a full and complete answer.

Comment: @jdv If there are related questions, asking them is **exactly** what comments are supposed to be for.

Comment: What are you planning the horizontal shelf itself to be made of?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking the whole structure would be approximately 120cm high? Please [edit] your question to include the information I have asked for.

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I'm talking about a question that has over 3 semi-related questions, many of which impact each other. I know WW.SE is more forgiving of such questions but it will be hard to come up with one comprehensive answer that isn't an essay with lots of caveats. Like, just considering what to say about the choice of 2x2cm "poles" is an answer in itself. Most wood poles of that size will end up being twisted hockey sticks over time in any reasonable situation.

Comment: Like, I really want the answer to be "let's redesign most of this based on what you want it to look like, and how you expect it to be used over time". For example, maybe a light frame of round hardwood poles with pegs or pins that allow a number of box-shelves to be placed along the length like bookshelves? Then the boxes can be moved as needed, and build for stiffness and material without have to worry about them being part of the overall construction. But, of course, this does not answer any of the questions here.

Comment: I've edited the question. Added the detail that I plan it to be about 120cm tall, the idea to use plywood for the base and removed the other questions that weren't my main concern.

Comment: What thickness of plywood are you planning on using? If it's 11 mm or 19 mm plywood, this should be fine. If it's 6 mm, I'd be nervous about its structural integrity -- but mostly because 6 mm plywood doesn't have much.

Comment: The answer to your core Q here is, it depends. The main variable is the weight these have to hold. If they won't be heavily loaded then your plan looks fine to me (although there are simpler and stronger ways you could construct it). So, minimum thickness? While @CharlieKilian correctly states that 6mm or 1/4" ply isn't very strong it *can* be used for boxes a little larger than you want here, I have harvested some from the bottoms of a couple of such boxes! But that said, go thicker and you will get a stronger box that can take more weight, more knocks and just generally hold together better.

Comment: I've just had a look at the revision history for the Question and see what you want this for, light duty in the kitchen. Given that 6mm plywood will be *absolutely fine*. You could even go thinner and get away with it — I would have no hesitation in building something like this using 3mm hardboard for the bottom!

Comment: The idea was to use 2cm solid wood for the poles and 1cm plywood for the rails and bottom. Since I never done any work with wood ever I wouldn't know if something like this would hold, especially having a tall structure. The motivation to use thinner plywood comes from the limitation of space I have on where I plan to place the finished shelf, as I have a tight constraint on width, each cm in thickness on the sides of the boxes would "eat" away the inside space since the finished box cannot exceed 17cm. Thank you very much for your kind comments, Charlie Kilian, Graphus, jdv and Martin Bonner.

Comment: Ahh yes, I was thrown off by the shelf dimension of 120 cm -- I misread that as being one of the dimensions for the box itself. Upon review, I completely agree with @Graphus.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the metric sizes but 1/4" baltic birch* ply with a frame of 3/4" x 1 1/2" of a construction grade wood has worked for me on a crate about 24" x 12" x 5" was shipped several times. Sorry for the imperial measurements we should in the US have gone metric many years ago.

*lauan plywood will also work although not nearly as durable